# how i can click on the second row in a table using protractor

Tags: protractor

i'm trying to use protractor to click on the second row of a table.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

so for example if i want to click on the row that contains eve what should i do ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to click the `td` element with `Eve` text, you can do it via ["by.cssContainingText"](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText):

```
element(by.cssContainingText("table tr td", "Eve")).click();
```

If you want to click the parent `tr` element:

```
element(by.xpath("//table/tr[td = 'Eve']")).click();
```

If you don't know if `Eve` is gonna be there and just need to click the second row in the table:

```
$$("table tr").get(1).click();  // indexing starts with 0
```